# How to specify in Spring XML configuration file class for a Map property?

Tags: java, spring

Here is what I mean, see following spring XML file:

```
<bean id = 'a' class="A">
   <property name="mapProperty">
       <map>
          <entry key="key1"><value>value1</value></entry>
       </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

And my class looks like following:

```
class A {
   HashMap mapProperty

}
```

How can I tell in spring XML file that Map to be injected is of type java.util.HashMap ? Or in general can I provide class name for the Map ?

Please note, I cannot change the `class A` to use `Map` instead of `HashMap`

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `util:map`

```
<util:map id="someId" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="key1">
        <value>value1</value>
    </entry>
</util:map>

<bean id="a" class="A">
    <property name="mapProperty" ref="someId">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Don't forget to add the `util` namespace.

Comment: @SachinThapa, can we use Map instead of HashMap in map-class? In other words if we are having HashMap as map-class , is it mandatory to have HashMap as variable for corresponding getter and setter methods?

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala The `map-class` here specifies the implementation. You can't instantiate a `Map` since it's an interface. But, yes, you can declare your variable as a `Map`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`util:map`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map) tag from the [`util`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util) schema. Here's an example:

```
<util:map id="utilmap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="key1" value="value1"/>
    <entry key="key2" value="value2"/>
</util:map>

<bean id = 'a' class="A">
   <property name="mapProperty" ref="utilmap" />
</bean>
```

BTW, you should not use raw type `HashMap`. Use a parameterized type instead - `HashMap<String, String>`.

Answer (score 6):

To extend [Sotirios Delimanolis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437104/1666398):  See [this example](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/create-list-and-map-beans-in-spring-xml#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1550515986464_5387) on how to include the `util` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
</beans>
```

Note that you will need to amend the `schemaLocation` as well ;)